# Python while loop not looping as many times as expected

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have 4 nested while loops they all look similar to the one bellow

```
x = 0.0    
while x <= 1.0:
    ls_alloc[0] = x
    x = x + 0.1
```

What I want it to do is add 0.1 to x each time while it is <= 1.0
The problem I am having is that it never actually goes into the while loop `x = 1.0`

I'm using python 2.7

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Did you mix up your variable names? Is `one` supposed to be `x`?

Comment: yes sorry they were all called one previously but I changed it in the question to avoid confusion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `0.1` can't be represented exactly as a `float`. What you get instead is a number that's slightly larger than `0.1`:

```
In [2]: '%.20f' % 0.1
Out[2]: '0.10000000000000000555'
```

This results in fewer iterations of the loop that you might expect. Also, `x` never hits precisely `1.0` (even though the latter *can* be represented exactly).

It is worth noting that this behaviour is a property of floating-point arithmetic in general, and is in no way specific to Python.

Comment: It is important to point out this is not a Python issue, rather it is a floating point issue.